# How to convert URL from database into image in List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am working with ASP.Net C# on Visual Studio, and am looking for a way to convert URLs for images (which are stored in the same directory as the website) into images in the list view.

Just in case I sounded a bit confusing: In my database I have a field for a URL, which links to an image in the same directory as my website. When I populate my list view, rather than display the URL in the list view, I want to process the URL and instead return the image into an image field in the list view. I have an unknown number of items in my database, hence why I cannot hard code anything.

I appreciate any ideas, links or help.

Comment: what have you tried. (You can use the url in your database to populate the Image.ImageUrl property or just code some html like this `<img src=\'' + databaseUrl + \'' />`

Comment: if you dont want to show image then dont use image tag istead use span

Comment: put some code i really dont understand the question do you want to show images or do you want to process url instead of images

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do want to show the images, but since I am populating my list view using an SQL Data Source (everything is through the front end GUI), I am unsure of how to convert my URL (which is taken from my DB) into an image in my list view.

Comment: give an example of the url stored in your db (i.e. is it fqdn such as http://yoursite.com/images/blah.jpg or is it partial i.e. /images/blah.jpg